# Failed to stop the worker thread, likely to create a Memory leak.

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, quartz-scheduler

I am using a servlet that implements ServletContextListener to start the quartz scheduler instance @ starup. In the  contextDestroyed() method, the scheduler instance is stopped.

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    try {
        Scheduler scheduler = QuartzSchedulerUtil.getCurrentScheduler();
        scheduler.shutdown(true);
        // Sleep for a bit so that we don't get any errors
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Driver mySqlDriver = DriverManager.getDriver(hibernateConnectionUrl);
        DriverManager.deregisterDriver(mySqlDriver);
    } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(QuartzServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(QuartzServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(QuartzServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
    System.out.println("THE QUARTZ APP STOPPED");
}
```

But when the application is deployed i get the memory leak warnings specifying that the woker threads are not stopping.

```
Jul 10, 2012 3:46:12 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/latest-raisin]
appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to
stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 10, 2012 3:46:12 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/latest-raisin]
appears to have started a thread named 
[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] but
has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 10, 2012 3:46:12 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/latest-raisin]
appears to have started a thread named
[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] but
has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jul 10, 2012 3:46:12 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/latest-raisin]
appears to have started a thread named
[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] but
has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I tried the solution as mentioned in the post - http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/15/4341.page
But still getting the Severe memory leak warnings when the appication is undeployed.

Comment: Are you sure `scheduler.shutdown(true);` is enough ? Maybe not a quartz issue but a c3p0 issue ? A timer is created in there also I think : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1/com/mchange/v2/async/ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property in `org.quartz.scheduler.interruptJobsOnShutdown`  to interrupt jobs if they are still in execution when you want to shutdown.